# Redux thunk doesn't display data on array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I am making a redux movie using react and redux-thunk.
I am still new in Redux. I know Redux thunk is a middleware to handle async function for API calls. My objective is to display api data in the component. I don't know the missing point.
Here is my code:
action.js

```
import API from "../api/index";
import axios from "axios";

export const MovieSuccess = (data) => ({
  type: MOVIE_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
});

export const MovieError = (data) => ({
  type: MOVIE_ERROR,
  payload: data,
});

export const MovieStart = () => ({
  type: MOVIE_START,
});

export const getMovies = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(MovieStart());
  return axios
    .get(API)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch(MovieSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(MovieError(err));
    });
};
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  movies: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const MovieReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MOVIE_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case MOVIE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: action.payload,
        loading: true,
        error: "",
      };
    case MOVIE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }
};

export default MovieReducer;
```

for the store, i put in index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import App from "./App";
import MovieReducer from "./redux/reducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(MovieReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import MainPage from "./Components/MainPage";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MainPage />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

MainPage.js

```
import MovieCard from "../MovieCard";
import SearchInput from "../SearchInput";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getMovies } from "../../redux/action";

const { Header, Content } = Layout;

const MainPage = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.listMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {props.movies.map((key, data) => (
          <div>
            <p>{key.id}</p>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Layout>
        <Header>
          <SearchInput />
        </Header>
        <Content>
          <MovieCard />
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  movies: state.movies,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  listMovies: (data) => dispatch(getMovies(data)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your getting any errors? If you are please update your question with more explanation, in the meanwhile this might be what's causing the problem:

```
{props.movies.map((key, data) => (
          <div>
            <p>{key.id}</p>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
          </div>
))}
```

try changing it to

```
{props.movies.map((data, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{data.id}</p>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
          </div>
))}
```

and if this is not the case, please provide more information on the nature of the problem that your facing.